# Eclipse JDT AST: How to write generated AST to java file?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am currently working with eclipse AST to generate source code. Other than in most examples, I am generating the source code from scratch and in a stand-alone application, as opposed to an eclipse plug-in.

When read in from an ASTParser, you can activate modifications by calling `recordModifications()`, but this doesn't work when the AST is created from scratch, e.g. by calling `newCompilationUnit()`.

Consequently, writing the source to file via a `Document` and `TextEdit` is not possible - there is an exception saying that modification recording hasn't been enabled.
Any experiences in generating AST from scratch and writing to file?
Thanks!

Comment: Lots of experience prettyprinting compilable ASTs for Java, but not with Eclipse.  Is Eclipse a requirement for your question?

Comment: Why do you want to write the "generated AST" to a file? Maybe its just phrasing, but I get the impression you want to write prettyprinted source text to a file, where that source text is generated from the AST.

Comment: Well, I am using Eclipse because it is widely used, and the "Java Development Tools" (JDT) AST implementation allows for round-trip engineering, so you can either generate code from an in-memory AST, or you can modify existing source code by doing minimal changes. "Generated" in this case means that the AST is built in memory programmatically.

Comment: You didn't actually answer my questions.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand it correctly. I'm not strictly bound to Eclipse, and I am actually only using a library from the Eclipse project. So: No, Eclipse isn't a requirement. And yes, I want to write prettyprinted source text to a file, and the source text is generated from an AST. A requirement is, however, that the AST works in a read/write fashion, so it allows modifications to existing source code as well as generation of source code from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create the file first, then generate an AST from it, like this:

```
ICompilationUnit unit = JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(file);
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
parser.setResolveBindings(true);
parser.setSource(unit);
// Parse the source code and generate an AST.
CompilationUnit ast = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
```

If the file is newly created and blank, then presumably the AST will be empty, You can then replace the root of the `ast` object and write it to the file. Also, if you are not tied to Eclipse, you could just do the same thing using the JSR199 standard and write that AST to a file in the normal way. See [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html) for an introduction.

Comment: Could you give an example for the "You can then replace the root of the ast object and write it to the file." part?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if I was very clear there. If you have already generated the file of Java code, so `file` in my code above is a real Java file, then the code I have given here should just parse it correctly and give you an AST that you can work with...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your suggestions!
In the meantime I found a way to emit the source code via an internal class "ASTFlattener", which creates a String representation of an AST. This works pretty well for me....

Comment: That is the best answer because you get a String and so answers the more general question "how getting a String from an AST?". It is especially useful if don't need a file at all (for testing, as an intermediate result, ..).

Answer (score 1):

I've just been trying to find the answer to the same question.
Based on the answers above, the most elegant solution I've found so far looks like:

```
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS4);
parser.setCompilerOptions(....);

Document document = new Document("");
parser.setSource(document.get().toCharArray());
CompilationUnit unit = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
unit.recordModifications();

TextEdit edits = unit.rewrite(document, null);
edits.apply(document);

// now write document.get() to file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the source from scratch, maybe you could write the minimal source able to be parsed to a temporary file, apply your modifications to the Ast, then write it back to that file as a text edit as you do otherwise. Then read the source. You could then transfer this to wherever you want.

There is probably a more elegant solution, but this may work.

Answer (score 0):

After created a compilation unit from AST I'm doing:

```
AST ast = AST.newAST(AST.JLS4);    
CompilationUnit unit = ast.newCompilationUnit();
```

... fill Compilation Unit and then ...

```
package.createCompilationUnit(className + ".java", unit.toString(), true, null);
```

Where:
`package` = `IPackageFragment`
`className` = `String` (generated class name)
`unit` => `CompilationUnit` ast
`true` => force replace
`null` => progress monitor